# Update query using JPA Query Annotation to Oracle 11g Hangs

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to update a simple row using Query Annotation with JPA to Oracle 11g

This is my code:

```
@Transactional()
@Modifying
@Query(value="UPDATE Irregularities SET IRREST_ID = 0 WHERE IRREGS_ID = 1006", nativeQuery = true)
int updateState();
```

This was working fine but for some reason is not working anymore. No error, just hangs.

If I try to run the same query with Oracle SQL Developer in the same BDD works fine.

Could be a lock table problem? Why works in SQL Developer but not in Springboot?

Thank you very much for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Do you see any locks on the DB?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Is there a simple way to check this? I tried to execute some queries that I found on the internet to check but didn't work.

Comment: FWIW There is no "JPA `@Query` annotation". That is Spring Data JPA != JPA API

Answer (score 0):

You can find locks with that query (run it as sysdba)

```
select
(select username || ' - ' || osuser || ' - ' || machine from v$session where sid=a.sid) blocker,
a.sid || ', ' ||
(select serial# from v$session where sid=a.sid) sid_serial,
' is blocking ',
(select username || ' - ' || osuser || ' - ' || machine from v$session where sid=b.sid) blockee,
b.sid || ', ' ||
(select serial# from v$session where sid=b.sid) sid_serial
from v$lock a, v$lock b
where a.block = 1
and b.request > 0
and a.id1 = b.id1
and a.id2 = b.id2;
```